# How to create haskell cabal package as output of haskell code?

Tags: haskell, code-generation, cabal

The Haskell project I am working on generates code(and tests for it) that is intended to be used as an independent Haskell library. I want to wrap it in a cabal project, so it can be included as a dependency.

I searched for a library interface for the cabal, so I can create a cabal project at a given directory by calling some functions, but found none.

I could, of course, just run bash commands from Haskell, but it looks ugly to me.

Is there any tool that will solve my problem in a nice way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [Cabal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal) package. You can parse an existing cabal file, change stuff in the data structures, and regenerate the text representation.

**Edit** in answer to comment:

I don't know of any tutorials. The links I gave are for the Haddock docs, and the mapping between data types and Cabal file text is pretty straightforward. So you should probably start by writing the code to produce a [`PackageDescription`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-3.6.2.0/docs/Distribution-Types-PackageDescription.html) value and then call [`writePackageDescription`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-3.6.2.0/docs/Distribution-PackageDescription-PrettyPrint.html) on it.

Note the existence of `emptyPackageDescription`, which lets you just specify the fields you want.

(Removed link to pretty printer class because `PackageDescription` isn't a member.)

Comment: I suspected that Cabal might have the functionality I seek, but I failed to understand where to start. Are there any manuals or examples on how to generate a minimal cabal project using the Cabal?

Comment: That might be what I need, thank you. I will try to make it work and then will probably accept your answer.